# Gulp - Babel - EcmaScript-6 - Redux / Unhandled stream error in pipe

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, redux, babeljs

I have a problem with gulp trying to get this app I found on GitHub up and running.

https://github.com/simpulton/eggly-redux

I appreciate if anyone would be interested to have a look at this.
Many thanks in advance.

My repo for this with adjusted package.json and added .babelrc file is here.

https://github.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux

Configuration files for quick look are here:

https://rawgit.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/master/package.json
https://rawgit.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/master/webpack.config.js
https://rawgit.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/master/gulpfile.babel.js
https://rawgit.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/master/.babelrc

It should normally be starting up with the following instructions indicated in the ReadMe file, but this did not work out for me.

```
git clone https://github.com/simpulton/eggly-redux.git
cd eggly-redux
npm i
gulp
```

Similar questions are already been asked. I have gone through all I
could find from answers to those here, but no luck. That's why I am
asking a new question.

Here is what I have done when it did not work out along with all my findings
I got the following installed just in case when it did not work in the
first place..

```
npm install -g npm  
npm install -g webpack  
npm install -g gulp  
npm install -g babel  
npm install -g browser-sync  
npm install browser-sync --save-dev  
npm install babel --save-dev  
npm install babel-register --save-dev  
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev   
npm uninstall babel  
npm install --global babel-cli  
npm install babel-cli --save-dev
```

And gulp still gives me the same error

```
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
 Error: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\client\app\app.js: Unknown option: C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\.babelrc.presets
    at Logger.error (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:58:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:126:29)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:107:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:168:35)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:229:12)
    at File.initOptions (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:147:75)
    at new File (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:137:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:164:16)
    at transpile (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:12:22)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:71:12)
```

I figured out that this is something to do with this task in

```
gulpfile.babel.js
    // use webpack.config.js to build modules
    gulp.task('webpack', () => {
      return gulp.src(paths.entry)
        .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
    });
```

so I changed

```
.pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config')))
```

to

```
.pipe(webpack(require('webpack-stream')))
```

in **gulpfile.babel.js**. Then gulp gives me the following:

```
[20:52:57] Requiring external module babel-register
(node:9156) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[20:52:58] Using gulpfile C:\projects-mts\@eggly-redux\gulpfile.babel.js
[20:52:58] Starting 'default'...
[20:52:58] Starting 'webpack'...
[20:52:58] Version: webpack 1.13.1
                  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
43db048c592b328cbb29.js  2.16 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[20:52:58] Finished 'webpack' after 366 ms
[20:52:58] Starting 'serve'...
[20:52:59] Finished 'serve' after 75 ms
[20:52:59] Starting 'watch'...
[20:52:59] Finished 'watch' after 46 ms
[20:52:59] Finished 'default' after 494 ms
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
Local: http://localhost:3000  
External: http://192.168.2.2:3000  
 ------------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:3001  
UI External: http://192.168.2.2:3001  
 ------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: client
```

along with a file called

https://rawgit.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/master/client/43db048c592b328cbb29.js

instead of **bundle.js** and my browser says

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/bundle.js"
if I rename that file to bundle.js then browser gives me
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
import 'bootstrap-css-only';
```

My versions are as follows:

```
$ npm -v  
3.9.5  

$ gulp -version  
[20:59:02] Requiring external module babel-register  
[20:59:02] CLI version 3.9.1  
[20:59:02] Local version 3.9.1  

$ webpack -v  
Hash: 396f0bfb9d565b6f60f0  
Version: webpack 1.13.1  
Time: 15ms
```

I noticed your comments after I tried the following :

Deleted the node_modules directory

```
npm install babel babel-register babel-cli babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-es2015-webpack browser-sync gulp gulp-rename gulp-template webpack webpack-stream css-loader raw-loader style-loader stylus-loader url-loader --save-dev

npm i
```

and now I get some other error. I think I made some progress

```
$ gulp
[15:24:35] Requiring external module babel-register
(node:12704) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[15:24:36] Using gulpfile C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\gulpfile.babel.js
[15:24:36] Starting 'default'...
[15:24:36] Starting 'webpack'...

stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
 Error: ./~/css-loader!./~/stylus-loader!./client/app/app.styl
Module build failed: TypeError: C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\client\app\app.styl:37:1
   33|   from
   34|     opacity 0
   35|   to
   36|     opacity 1
   37|
-------^

Path must be a string. Received undefined

    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at extname (path.js:887:5)
    at new SourceMapper (C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\stylus\lib\visitor\sourcemapper.js:41:7)
    at Renderer.render (C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\stylus\lib\renderer.js:94:9)
    at C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\stylus-loader\index.js:149:12
    at tryCatchReject (C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:840:30)
    at runContinuation1 (C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:799:4)
    at Fulfilled.when (C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:590:4)
    at Pending.run (C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:481:13)
    at Scheduler._drain (C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\node_modules\when\lib\Scheduler.js:62:19)
 @ ./client/app/app.styl 4:14-122./~/css-loader!./~/stylus-loader!./client/app/components/categories/categories.styl
Module build failed: TypeError: C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\client\app\components\categories\categories.styl:35:1
   31|     overflow-x hidden
   32|     overflow-y auto /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
   33|     background-color #2B2828
   34|     border-right 1px solid #7B807E
   35|
-------^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error you get "Unknown option: .babelrc.presets" comes from the [wrong version](https://github.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/blob/master/package.json#L22) of babel-core used to build your project. Update the version to `6.9`. The version must be equal to the [babel-preset-es2015 version](https://github.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/blob/master/package.json#L24)

Comment: Thank you Damien. Unfortunately that on its own did not help. But I got inspired and re-installed certain libraries. I added what I have done at the end of my question. I think I have progress. It looks like now webpack is not happy with the given loaders. Any idea ?

Comment: here is my commit

https://github.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/commit/a8fa03bb674e646d2ce7b5118bb269df29a4dcad

Comment: No idea sorry. may be writting a new post with this particular question might give more answer more more people :)

Comment: That I could resolve in the same way, but this time by uninstalling and re-installing stylus and stylus-loader. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  @Damien Leroux is right.

You altered the original project with a `.babelrc` file. The babel version that is in the project doesn't understand the `presets` setting yet. If you update `babel-core` to the current version it will work. Note that you have to update `babel-loader` as well:

```
npm uninstall babel-core --save-dev
npm uninstall babel-loader --save-dev
npm install babel-core --save-dev
npm install babel-loader --save-dev
```

After this it worked for me. Your package.json should now be updated:

  `"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^5.0.0",`

Is now

  `"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",`

Comment: Thanks Bart, that did not solve my problem, but I got inspired and I re-installed most of the packages I suspected and now I get some new error. apparently webpack is not happy with the loaders for some reason. Any idea what that could be ?

Comment: here is my commit

https://github.com/mehmettugrulsahin/eggly-redux/commit/a8fa03bb674e646d2ce7b5118bb269df29a4dcad

Comment: Hmpphh.. Stop changing everything! Like I said, it workd on my machine. Can you first confirm that the original package works if you don't change anything? :)

Comment: I figured that it did not work by me this time because of the stylus and stylus-loader versions. I re-installed them like you have done with babel-core and babel-loader and I managed to get the app up and running. I have some errors reported by the browser though. But so far so good. Apparently uninstalling and re-installing certain packages makes a difference. Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I got the app up and running like this

```
$ gulp
[21:16:33] Requiring external module babel-register
(node:10132) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[21:16:34] Using gulpfile C:\projects-mts\eggly-redux\gulpfile.babel.js
[21:16:34] Starting 'default'...
[21:16:34] Starting 'webpack'...
[21:16:40] Version: webpack 1.13.1
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  2.36 MB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  2.74 MB       0  [emitted]  main
[21:16:40] Finished 'webpack' after 5.19 s
[21:16:40] Starting 'serve'...
[21:16:40] Finished 'serve' after 102 ms
[21:16:40] Starting 'watch'...
[21:16:40] Finished 'watch' after 56 ms
[21:16:40] Finished 'default' after 5.37 s

[BS] Serving files from: client
```

by applying the following:

```
npm uninstall babel-core --save-dev
npm uninstall babel-loader --save-dev
npm uninstall stylus --save-dev
npm uninstall stylus-loader --save-dev
npm install babel-core --save-dev
npm install babel-loader --save-dev
npm install stylus --save-dev
npm install stylus-loader --save-dev
```

Many thanks for the inspiration and valuable answers!